# issue in loading image in img src in angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I uploaded an image using nodes and angular. I try to view uploaded images from my local disk

```
<img ng-src="my location/file.png">
```

but it does not view the image file. what I need to do. Is something I need to set for loading image from local directory?

Comment: `localhost:8080/mylocation/file.png` does it resolve in the browser? Is your server running? Is the file available under that url?

Answer (score -2):

**If you are using any scope variable then only add ng-src otherwise
src would work normally.**

Try:

```
<img src="my location/file.png">
```

Comment: i also use img src it seems to be not loading image . when i hover on browser console it show http://localhost:8080/mylocation/file.png

Comment: `ng-src` is an angular-wrapper over `src` attribute. It functions exactly as `src` only it waits for the passed value interpolation before making the http call to fetch the requested resource.

Comment: ok. does any thing i need to do in server.js for loading local disk image